# When I scroll the table gets stick to the position and only the text gets scrolled. I want it to scroll with the text

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-text

When I scroll the table gets stick to the position and only the text gets scrolled. It should scroll with the text.
The table was created with entry widget. The code does not throw any error but the scrolling is not working properly.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
app = tk.Tk(screenName="main")
#Font and orientation setup
app.geometry('600x200')

txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(app, width=50, height=10)
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0,   sticky=E+W+N+S)
txtbox.insert(INSERT,".\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n Physical Properties.\n.\n.\n Physical Properties",)
fortable1 = Frame(txtbox, padx=5, pady=5,width=500,height=200 )
fortable1.place(x=0,y=5)
class Table:

    def __init__(self, fortable1):

        # code for creating table
        self.e = Entry(fortable1, width=12, fg='blue', bg="#FFFFE0",
                       font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)

        self.e.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.e.insert(END, lst[0][0])
        self.e = Entry(fortable1, width=12, bg="#FFFFE0",
                       font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)

        self.e.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e.insert(END, lst[0][1])
        self.e = Entry(fortable1, width=12, bg="#FFFFE0",
                       font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)

        self.e.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.e.insert(END, lst[0][2])
        self.e = Entry(fortable1, width=12, bg="#FFFFE0",
                       font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)

        self.e.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.e.insert(END, lst[0][3])

        for i in range(1, total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                self.e = Entry(fortable1, width=12, bg="#FFFFE0",
                               font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)

                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])


lst = [("Sr/N", 'Parameter', 'Value', "Remarks"),
       (1, 'Grade Category', '1', '-'),
       (2, 'Equivalant Grade', 'N/A', "No such grades \n in our record"),
       (3, 'Liquidus', 'Tliq', '_'),
       (4, 'Solidus', 'Tsol', '_')]

total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])
t = Table(fortable1)
app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the frame `fortable1` which holds the table is not part of the content of `txtbox` since it is just put on top of `txtbox` using `.place()`. You need to use `txtbox.window_create()` to insert the frame into the text box instead.

Below is the updated code:

```py
...
txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(app, width=50, height=10)
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0,   sticky=E+W+N+S)
fortable1 = Frame(txtbox, padx=5, pady=5,width=500,height=200 )
#fortable1.place(x=0,y=5)
# insert the frame using .window_create()
txtbox.window_create(INSERT, window=fortable1)
txtbox.insert(INSERT, "\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n Physical Properties.\n.\n.\n Physical Properties")
...
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the help . One more doubt, I want to print all the Information in the text box how to do that?

Comment: @PrashantPriyadarshi It is better to raise a new question on that.  Note that currently you cannot get all the content from those entry boxes because you use only one instance variable `self.e` for all the entry widgets.